# Migrate Service Fabric Reliable Collections to Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

We are in the process of migrating our Service Fabric services to Kubernetes. Most of them were "stateless" services and were easy to migrate. However, we have one "stateful" service that uses SF's Reliable Collections pretty heavily.

K8s has Statefulsets, but that's not really comparable to SF's reliable collections.

Is there a .NET library or other solution to implement something similar to SF's Reliable Collections in K8s?

Comment: Could you clarify what specifically does not suit you when using Statefulsets?

Comment: @IvanM. Can't say I've used Statefulsets a lot yet, but as it related to my issue, it makes it easier to keep stateful volumes (PV/PVCs) for each instance, even after pod restarts. However, they don't solve the coordination problem (saving data on the primary instance will automatically replicate to the others for recovery when the primary instance dies). That's what SF reliable collections does out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK this cannot be done by using a .Net library.
K8 is all about orchestration. SF on the other hand is both an orchestrator + rich programming /application model + state management.
If you want to do something like reliable collection in K8 then you have to either

A) built your own replication solution with leader election and all.

B) use private etcd/cockroachdb etc. store

This article is pretty good in terms of differences.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/azuredev/service-fabric-and-kubernetes-comparison-part-1-distributed-systems-architecture#split-brain-and-other-stateful-disasters

"Existing systems provide varying levels of support for microservices, the most prominent being Nirmata, Akka, Bluemix, Kubernetes, Mesos, and AWS Lambda [there’s a mixed bag!!]. SF is more powerful: **it is the only data-ware orchestration system today for stateful microservices**"

Answer (score 1):

> However, they don't solve the coordination problem (saving data on the primary instance will automatically replicate to the others for recovery when the primary instance dies). That's what SF reliable collections does out of the box.

StatefulSets are valuable for applications that require one or more of the following.

- Stable (persistent), unique network identifiers.
- Stable, persistent storage.
- Ordered, graceful deployment and scaling.
- Ordered, automated rolling updates.

If your application doesn't require any of these, you should deploy your application using a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

#### There is a good Kubernetes guide on how to **Run a Replicated Stateful Application**  [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/).

> This page shows how to run a replicated stateful application using a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) controller. This application is a replicated MySQL database. The example topology has a single primary server and multiple replicas, using asynchronous row-based replication.

The StatefulSet controller starts Pods one at a time, in order by their ordinal index. It waits until each Pod reports being Ready before starting the next one. And it is used to perform orderly startup of MySQL replication by running [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).

#### Operators can help

While [operators](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/)  are not necessary, they can help run stateful apps on Kubernetes with features like application-level HA management, backups, and restore.

You can use existing Operators or [develop](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/#writing-operator) your own. The operator package includes all the configurations needed to deploy and manage the application from a Kubernetes point of view – from a StatefulSet to be used to any required storage, rollout strategies, persistence and affinity configuration, and more. Kubernetes will then rely on the operator to validate instances of the application against the specification to ensure it runs in the same way across instances in all clusters it is deployed in.

Some DB operators:

- You can deploy MySQL database using Kubernetes operator developed by Oracle (currently is in a **preview state**):
  https://github.com/mysql/mysql-operator
- There’s also a PostgreSQL operator by Crunchydata to deploy PostgreSQL to Kubernetes:
  https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator
- MongoDB owns an operator to deploy MongoDB Enterprise to a Kubernetes cluster:
  https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-enterprise-kubernetes

**You can find ready-made operators on [OperatorHub.io](https://operatorhub.io/) to suit your use case.**

Comment: I understand the basics here, but I still don't see this as a replacement for Reliable Collections. In the MySQL example, It's still up to MySQL to synchronize the data of the various instances. And the first pod is always primary, so if it goes down, writes cannot occur until it comes back up. With Reliable collections, once the primary goes down, another instance can be promoted to primary immediately, without downtime. And it handles the synchronization of all the replicas' data. So yes, I could build this all from scratch, but that doesn't answer my initial question.

Comment: That's part of my point. There is no DB. The data is stored along side the instance and replicated across the instances. All automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no built-in feature to replicate data across the instances in Kubernetes. Consider using shared network location/fs for persistent storage like [AWS EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-persistent-storage/) for EKS, or [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume) for AKS, or [NFS storage](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner) for on-premise k8s cluster.